# swapping values of two variables, order of precedence?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

```
var a = 1, b = 9;
a, b = b, a;
console.log(a,b)

1 9
```

Is possible that the assignments were carried out in left-to-right order? So, "a" would take the value of "b" and and "b" the value of "a".

Comment: What are you trying to do? The above statements assign as expected. Not what YOU expected, but what JS implementation expects. Read up on the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: `a,b = b, a` is same as `b = a`. Besides, it logs 1 and 9, not 9 9

Comment: `a, b = b, a` is one expressionm so you could write `(a, b = b, a);` which sort of translates to [`a;`:do nothing `b=b;`:also do nothing `a;`:do nothing again]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping values should be pretty simple:

```
var temp = b;
b = a;
a = temp;
```

**EDIT:** if it's all about integers, swapping can happen even without additional variable:

```
b = b - a;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
```

Comment: It is not so simple when the values are not numbers else i.e. an array or an object

Comment: If the array is the case, then put it in your question with more clarifications. Otherwise, I suppose your initial question was answered.